# How can I convert table rows to specific group of format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and I want to output records in 2 formats.

In the first output I want table rows to be appear as left and right group you can see in the image.
and in the second output I want rows as one left and one right.

I am using SQL Server.

[image: description 1]

[image]

[image]

I have tried with pivot but not succeed.

Comment: This is not something you should be doing in `T-SQL`. This is something that should be handles by your reporting layer. The `T-SQL` to do this would require unnatural `JOINs` and the results cannot be paged in SSMS.

Comment: For some help with achieving Output 1, you could take a look into [`NTILE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx "NTILE (Transact-SQL)").

Comment: @MarkD paging is not imp for now - wt i want is 5-5 records, left -right ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you HAVE TO do things like this in T-SQL, this is one way of doing it...

```
----------------------------
--  Display 1
----------------------------
DECLARE @ColBreak INT = 5
;WITH MyTable (SrNo, ItemNo, Qty) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 150 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'A2', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'A3', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'A4', 150 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'A5', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'A6', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'A7', 150 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'A8', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'A9', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'A10', 150
)
,Column1 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable T1
    WHERE SrNo  <= @ColBreak
)
,Column2 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable T1
    WHERE SrNo  > @ColBreak
)
SELECT *
FROM Column1 T1
JOIN Column2 T2 ON T1.SrNo + @ColBreak = T2.SrNo

----------------------------
--  Display 2
----------------------------

;WITH MyTable (SrNo, ItemNo, Qty) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'A1', 150 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'A2', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'A3', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'A4', 150 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'A5', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'A6', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'A7', 150 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'A8', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'A9', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'A10', 150
)
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T1
JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.SrNo + 1 = T2.SrNo
WHERE T1.SrNo % 2 != 0
```